# How to make a link that closes the browser window?

Tags: javascript, html

How to make a link that closes the window (browser window)?
I want to create a span style :

```js
    <span style="background:white;border-radius:0em;
                 padding:1em;border:2px solid #ff1744;
                 box-shadow:3px 3px 5px #bdbdbd;
                 color:#ff1744">
      <b>END COURSE</b>
    </span>
```

That has a link to close the window (browser window)!

Ok so basically I want to use that script that closes the window (browser window), in a .xml script. I will host the script and use it. This will act like a gadget.

This is where the script goes into the xml (highlighted bold)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>  
<Module> 
  <ModulePrefs title="Close Course" />  
  <Content type="html"> 
     <![CDATA[  
**CODE GOES HERE**
     ]]>
  </Content>  
</Module>
```

Thanks
Darren

Comment: please provide code so i will check it

Comment: But I do not know how to integrate it.

Comment: i am confuse with your question which window you have to close website window or browser window???

Comment: The browser window because I have a script to open a centered one, and when they are ready with it I want  it to close by pressing the button I mentioned above

Comment: I would recommend editing your question with the additional details you provided in the comments; it will help attract more positive feedback to your question.

Comment: @Ravi Sukhadia The browser window, not the tab(website window)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with javascript window.close(). http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_close.asp